# "Unfortunately Design1 has stopped"

Tags: android

I am new in `Android`. My app name is `Design1` My app is running successfully in `Emulator`. I copied the apk file from `C:\Users\Rahul\AndroidStudioProjects\Design1\app\build\outputs\apk` to my phone and installed it there. But when I try to open the app in my `ASUS ZENFONE MAX` phone I got a message that "`Unfortunately Design1 1 has stopped`". I have checked `logcat` and set the `dropdown` to `ERROR` to see if any error occurs or not. But no errors I got when running in simulator. Please tell if there any specific way to build the APK file or I can directly copy from apk file location. If the app is running in emulator then why it is not running in my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May you have have Enabled Instant run just Disable it

First Disable Instant run than Build apk

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Disable Instant Run.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this in your device, Go to settings, enable developer options and USB debugging. Then connect it to your computer and check it in Android Studio logcat. 
The following might be the causes for the crash.

- This might have occured due to permission enabling in your app,
  provided if you are using any camera, storage or location.
- If your app is working in online then you might have not checked the 
  network connection.

Comment: I tried connecting my device after enabling developer option and USB debuggin. But my device does not shows up as a emulator. Still shows NO USB DEVICES OR RUNNING EMULATOR DETECTED

Comment: @ShanBiswas Then it means that you have not installed the adb device drive. Refer this link on installing the driver. I hope this answered your question. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html